# Two tables in mysql with same name but different case

Tags: mysql

Somehow in our Mysql database (Engine version: 5.7.22), two tables with the same name but with the different cases are created.
Now I am not able to do any select/drop/rename operation on any of those tables.

[image]

Further, I checked in information schema, there exist multiple entries for the same.

[image]

I have gone through StackOverflow to find the solution but unable to do so.

How can I drop one of these tables, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `amp_poc` *schema* has case sensitive `collation` allowing you to have two with the same name but different characters cases.

To see the default character set and `collation` for a given database, use these queries: `USE db_name; SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database`

Alternatively, to display the values without changing the default database
`SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

You can drop either one just like any other table just be sure you have the character casing correct for the one you intended to delete! `drop table` or `drop TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your server with

> lower_case_table_names = 0

then drop your table using the exact casing of the name then switch the server back to

> lower_case_table_names = 1

to prevent similar issues in the future. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html